# Handling unicode characters in Java and write the results in mysql and HBase

Tags: java, mysql, json, unicode

I have a large volume of twitter dataset where each tweet is stored as a JSON object in which one of the field is tweet text which is a sequence of unicode characters. What I need to do is store this tweet text in MySql and HBase. Naturally MySql and HBase doesn't store unicode characters by default and I tried a number of approaches including changing the format of data storage in MySql. However in order to process this 1TB dataset I use map reduce to extract out the relevant fields from each JSON Object and write the output as a sequence of string such as:

```
1000000069:2014-04-20+09:23:41,457811834188607488%3A1%3ART+%40followback_707%3A+Retweet+this+%3F+ALL+%3F+WHO+%3F+RETWEETS+%3F+WANT+%3F+NEW+FOLLOWERS+FAST+%3F+%3F+%23FollowPyramid+%3F+%23TeamFollowBack%
```

(The key value pairs are separated after the first comma so in the above text `1000000069:2014-04-20+09:23:41` is the key and everything after that is the text information. The numbers in the initial are the tweet ID and then the sentiment score of the tweet.)

Now in the above text we can see that some characters were correctly encoded however there are texts that are complete illegible because their storage was not properly handled. The bigger challenge here is handling the text in the map reduce job and writing the output from this map reduce job correctly so that its fit for storage in the required stores i.e. MySql and HBase.

```
1000001353:2014-04-28+13:20:59,460770655601164288%3A0%3A%22%40FuckinFather_%3A+%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F+%3F+%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F.%22+%3F+%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F+%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F+%3F+%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F+%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F.
```

Actually the sequence of %3F we see are all decoded as question marks, which results in complete loss of tweet text information. I have been using `URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8)` function to encode the tweet text, however apparently it only works for some set of strings, but not for other type of characters. Is there some way that I can use that perfectly encodes all type of tweet text correctly for storage into MySql database and HBase.

The snippet of code that I am using to write down data from my reducer is given below:

My mapper function:

```
public class TweetParsingMapper {
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        List<HashMap<String, Integer>> wordSentimentScoringList = createAffinDataSet();
        HashSet<String> censorList = createCensorList();
        try{
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String jsonString;
            while((jsonString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                JSONObject tweetInfo = new org.json.JSONObject(jsonString);
                String tweetText = tweetInfo.get("tweetText").toString();
                String tweetId = tweetInfo.get("tweetId").toString();
                String userId = tweetInfo.get("userId").toString();
                String timeStamp = tweetInfo.get("timeStamp").toString();
                Integer sentimentScore = calculateSentimentScore(wordSentimentScoringList, tweetText);
                String censoredTweet = censorTweet(censorList, tweetText);
                censoredTweet = censoredTweet.replace("\n", "+delimiterfornewline+");
                censoredTweet = censoredTweet.replace("\r", "+delimiterforcarriagereturn+");
                censoredTweet = censoredTweet.replace(",", "+delimiterforcomma+");
                censoredTweet = tweetId + ":" + sentimentScore.toString() + ":"+ censoredTweet;
                String requestKey = userId + ":" + timeStamp;
                System.out.println(requestKey + "\t" + censoredTweet);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

My reducer function:

```
{
        try{
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String input = null;
            String requestKey = null;
            String currentRequestKey = null;
            List<String> responseString = new ArrayList<String>();
            while((input = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                String[] mapperResposeSet = input.split("\t", 2);
                requestKey = mapperResposeSet[0];
                if(requestKey.equals(currentRequestKey) && currentRequestKey != null){
                    if(!responseString.contains(mapperResposeSet[1]))
                        responseString.add(mapperResposeSet[1]);
                }
                else{
                    if(currentRequestKey != null){
                        StringBuilder finalResponse = new StringBuilder();

                        for(String str : responseString){
                            finalResponse.append(str);
                            finalResponse.append("+delimiter+");
                        }
                        System.out.println(currentRequestKey + "," + URLEncoder.encode(finalResponse.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                        responseString.clear();
                    }
                    currentRequestKey = requestKey;
                    responseString.add(mapperResposeSet[1]);
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

One of the sample tweet object is:

```
{"timeStamp": "2014-06-25+08:54:16", "tweetText": "\uff62\u30c9\u30e9\u30b4\u30f3\u30b3\u30a4\u30f3\u30ba\uff63\u3092\u59cb\u3081\u305f\u3088\uff01\u30b8\u30e3\u30e9\u30b8\u30e3\u30e9\u30b3\u30a4\u30f3\u304c\u8d85\u723d\u5feb\uff01\u4e00\u7dd2\u306b\u3042\u305d\u307c\uff01 http://t.co/An4nuiswy1 #\u30c9\u30e9\u30b3\u30a4", "uId": "1669549520", "ht": ["\u30c9\u30e9\u30b3\u30a4"], "tweetId": "481722030383828994"}
```

Comment: ｢ドラゴンコインズ｣を始めたよ！ジャラジャラコイン... ?  Is that what the tweet says?

Comment: Do you know were the `\u` syntax is coming from?  We need to get past it to insert into MySQL.

Comment: Yes thats is the actual tweet, as per your second question, the \u is actually present in the JSON object (I think it is for depicting that the character is a unicode character) that is written into the files from which I am parsing the data. These files are stored in a S3 bucket, and are of approximately of 1.7GB each. I was also thinking that can I convert all tweet text into bytes and stores these bytes in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You could either store it as is -- that is, 6 bytes per 'character' (\uxxxx).  If you could get that turned into utf8, it would take half the space.  For example the 6 characters \u30c9 represents Katakana DO; so does the hex e38389 in utf8, which would store as 3 bytes.

In PHP (version >= 5.4), this will give the utf8 instead of the \uxxxx:
$t = json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

I do not know the equivalent in Java.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I do not have any experience in PHP and also I am writing a map reduce job for processing this data so I will have to stick to java or python

Comment: Which Java or Python library for JSON is being used?  Provide me a like to the online docs, _maybe_ I can spot what needs to be done.